# redux thunk calling two different api requests

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

trying to call two api's in an action. When one is complete call the other then on the last one pass it off to a reducer.
Looks like my getAttending is getting called at the same time as post and not after post is completed. I'm new to redux-thunk and thought I could just call them one after another as the completed.

```
   export function postDeclined(id){
        let post = axios.post(blaBla.com);
        let getAttending = axios.get(attending.com);
        return (dispatch) => {
            post.then(()=>{
                getAttending.then(({data})=>{
                    dispatch({
                        type: type.NOT_GOING,
                        payload: data.data
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing the api calls like this:

```
 export function postDeclined(id){
        return (dispatch) => {
             axios.post(blaBla.com).then(()=>{
                 axios.get(attending.com).then(({data})=>{
                    dispatch({
                        type: type.NOT_GOING,
                        payload: data.data
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

When you "declared" the calls, you were actually calling the API... so it was doing async...

Answer (score 1):

I'd add async/await to your babel config. Makes reading/debugging these things a lot easier.

```
export const postDeclined => (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  const post await axios.post(blaBla.com);
  const getAttending = await axios.get(attending.com);
  return dispatch({
    type: type.NOT_GOING,
    payload: getAttending.data
  });
};
```

Comment: What does postDeclined => (id) => async (dispatch) =>  is async some method from await ? or just a name for the wrapper chain method.

Comment: The async keyword makes a function that returns a promise. The await keyword makes the line a synchronous call, and will not proceed until the promise has been resolved.  

https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait

Answer (score 0):

There is a very common problem with the code sample. The function does two things at once: do calls to apis and dispatch an action. Also, please note, that you can chain Promises, you don't need that intermediate callback:

```
 export const postDeclined = id =>
   axios.post(blaBla.com).then(axios.get(attending.com));

 export const notifyNotGoing = dispatch => promisedResult =>
   promisedResult.then(({data}) =>
     dispatch({
       type: type.NOT_GOING,
       payload: data.data
     })
   );
```

And then you can call your function like that:

```
notifyNotGoing(dispatch)(postDeclined(2))
```

or using composition and currying (I personally prefer [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/))

```
const prog = compose(notifyNotGoing(dispatch), postDeclined)
prog(2)
```